# Selenium WebDriver - Facebook Posting Issue

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation, webdriver

I'm really having trouble automating the facebook posting process.
My script is simply unable to track the textarea in our news feed correctly.

I've tried different selectors, even the ones suggested by Selenium IDE but got no avail.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
    //xpath for status update box
    WebElement statusUpdateBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath(DemoTestData.XPATH_STATUSUPDATE_BTN));
    //click the status update box
    driver.findElement((By.xpath(DemoTestData.XPATH_STATUSUPDATE_BTN))).click();
    //input data in the status update box
    statusUpdateBox.sendKeys(DemoTestData.DATA_STATUSUPDATE_MSG);
    WebElement postButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath(DemoTestData.XPATH_STATUSUPDATE_BTN));
    //click 'post' button
    postButton.click();
```

The xPath for

```
DemoTestData.XPATH_STATUSUPDATE_BTN = "html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div[1]/div/div[2]/textarea";
```

What am possibly missing?
Thanks a lot. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I've found. When I checked your xpath in my FB page it returned no results. (a very handy tool is a plugin called free simple firepath in firefox, be sure to get it if you don't!)

It seems unlikely that the button has an xpath ending with "textarea" are you sure that is correct?

When you run your test does the text get filled in? If not, the (first) problem is probably the findElement of the textbox.

When I looked some more I found that the css is actually very simple "textarea" . So if you'd use driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(“textarea”))
that should return the text area.

The button has a bit of a strange css (to me, but I am quite new to this as well), but I beleieve you could find that by the text in it. In my language it says "Plaatsen" It might say something different for you. Check in Firepath!

The something like driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[text()[contains(.,'Plaatsen')]]"))  should return the button.

I hope it helps! And I hope you found this answer useful, any tips on that would appreciated, it my first time answering something on the mighty Stack Overflow!

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for this. I did used firepath to check and use xpath directories when developing test scripts.

Comment: However, I've tried the following lines below but the WebDriver is still unable to write inputs onto the said text area field:

Comment: driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#placeholder-7rfdf")).sendKeys(DemoTestData.DATA_STATUSUPDATE_MSG);

Comment: driver.findElement(By.linkText("What's on your mind?")).sendKeys(DemoTestData.DATA_STATUSUPDATE_MSG);

Comment: driver.findElement((By.cssSelector("textarea"))).sendKeys("123 test");

Comment: I've tried it with the "textarea" css and it works fine for me. Maybe you can provide us with the stack strace to look a bit closer at whats happening ?

Comment: Hey Chai! textarea works well by now. Thanks for that! :)
I've got another problem here, which I also tried solving by cssSelector, linkText, xpath, name, className, id but got no avail. Can you please check the 'Post' button if that works to you as well? And how does that work to you?

Comment: Hi, I've tried By.XPath("//*[text()[contains(.,'Plaatsen')]]") and it does work here. However I did get some errors about "non clickable...another element would recieve the click" and so forth. If you get that error: I solved it by adding a wait before clicking post. Apparently after entering the text, the block moves/expands so that the button moves a bit. I at least, had to wait for that and then it worked. Again, if you post something about the specific execptions it will be easier to help!

Comment: Hi Chai! I was also able to work my way to get that post button working just now. I've used a relative xPath directory + waitUntil. 

Thank you so much! I'll select yo answer as the solution for my question. Have a nice day ahead! :D